# Using RXJS, is there a way to produce an observable that emits when the number of items, CURRENTLY emitted by the source Observables, is the same?

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs, rxjs-observables

I have two observables (obs1 and obs2) that I want to pay attention to. They never complete and over their lifetime I can expect that they emit the same number of items. I cannot know which one will emit first. I need something that will emit every time the source observables have each emitted their nth item. So, I am looking for an observable that acts in either of these ways:

- (a) It emits every time the source observables have each emitted the same number of items.
- (b) It emits every time the source observable, that has currently emitted the least amount of items, makes an emission.

### **Example for a:**

If **obs1** emits its **1st item** and then **obs2** emits its **1st item**, **myObservable** will produce its **1st emission**.
Then if **obs2** emits a **2nd** and **3rd item** nothing will happen until **obs1** emits its **2nd item** and only then will **myObservable** produce its **2nd emission**.

[(a) When source observables have the same number of items emitted.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rlxT6.png)

[(b) Whenever, across all the source observables, the lowest number of items emitted increases.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2UIXg.png)

Comment: This really sounds like an [`XY question`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378)

Comment: It probably is an XY question to some degree. I have been searching for this kind of solution for a while since I often find problems that I think would be solved by this kind of observable. I have glances at zip, but did not understand this is how it worked, so I am grateful for all the answerers.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## RxJS#zip

Zip does extactly what you're after.

For example, consider these two intervals that emit 5 times each but at different rates:

```ts
zip(
  interval(1000).pipe(map(v => v + 10) , take(5)), 
  interval(1500).pipe(map(v => v + 100), take(5))
).subscribe(console.log);
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you want the "zip" function (or maybe combineLatest).

https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/zip

https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/combineLatest

https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/understand-rxjs-operators-by-eating-a-pizza/